# ListView's adapter only shows text of first item after fragment resumes from backstack

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a ListView adapter that shows a list of cards with words on them. These cards can be dragged out or dropped in, with a call to `notifyDataSetChanged()`. When I return to this fragment's instance from the back stack, only the first card in the list has it's textview set with the word text. I should add that when I call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the adapter's `getView()` before I set the text on the ViewHolder object, the text appears after a noticeable delay (a little less than .5 seconds). Here is the adapter:

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ItemBaseAdapter {

public ItemListAdapter(Context context, List<WordCard> wordCards) {
    super(context, wordCards);
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;

    // reuse views
    if (rowView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_word, null);

       ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.word_text);
        viewHolder.mCloseBtn =  (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(mWordCards.get(position).getWord());
        holder.mCloseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mWordCards.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        rowView.setOnDragListener(new ItemDragListener(mWordCards.get(position)));
    }

    return rowView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView mCloseBtn;
}
}
```

It is set in the fragment's onCreateView:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);
    init(rootView);

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

private void init(View rootView) {
    mGamePresenter = new GamePresenter(this);

    mListView1 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    mListView2 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview2);
    mListView3 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview3);
    mListView4 = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview4);
    mGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_grid);

    mGridEmptyStateLl = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_empty_state_ll);

    mCodePanel1 = (LinearLayoutAbsListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.code_panel1);
    mCodePanel1.setOnDragListener(new ViewDragListener(mGamePresenter));
    mCodePanel1.setAbsListView(mListView1);
    mCodePanel2 = (LinearLayoutAbsListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.code_panel2);
    mCodePanel2.setOnDragListener(new ViewDragListener(mGamePresenter));
    mCodePanel2.setAbsListView(mListView2);
    mCodePanel3 = (LinearLayoutAbsListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.code_panel3);
    mCodePanel3.setOnDragListener(new ViewDragListener(mGamePresenter));
    mCodePanel3.setAbsListView(mListView3);
    mCodePanel4 = (LinearLayoutAbsListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.code_panel4);
    mCodePanel4.setOnDragListener(new ViewDragListener(mGamePresenter));
    mCodePanel4.setAbsListView(mListView4);
    mGridPanel = (LinearLayoutAbsListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_panel);
    mGridPanel.setOnDragListener(new ViewDragListener(mGamePresenter));
    mGridPanel.setAbsListView(mGridView);

    mGridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new GridItemLongClickListener(mGamePresenter));

    if (mGridList != null) {
        onWordListComplete(mGridList);
    }

    if (mPanel1List == null) {
        mPanel1List = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    if (mPanel2List == null) {
        mPanel2List = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    if (mPanel3List == null) {
        mPanel3List = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    if (mPanel4List == null) {
        mPanel4List = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    mItemListAdapter1 = new ItemListAdapter(getContext(), mPanel1List);
    mItemListAdapter2 = new ItemListAdapter(getContext(), mPanel2List);
    mItemListAdapter3 = new ItemListAdapter(getContext(), mPanel3List);
    mItemListAdapter4 = new ItemListAdapter(getContext(), mPanel4List);

    mListView1.setAdapter(mItemListAdapter1);
    mListView1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListItemLongClickListener());
    mListView2.setAdapter(mItemListAdapter2);
    mListView2.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListItemLongClickListener());
    mListView3.setAdapter(mItemListAdapter3);
    mListView3.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListItemLongClickListener());
    mListView4.setAdapter(mItemListAdapter4);
    mListView4.setOnItemLongClickListener(new ListItemLongClickListener());
}
```

Screenshot before returning to fragment instance:

[image: Screenshot before returning to fragment instance]

Screenshot after returning to fragment instance:

[image: Screenshot after returning to fragment instance]

Comment: why are you using setRetainInstance(true); in onResume()?

Comment: For orientation change. I removed this but it has no effect on the listview when I go back to the fragment.

Comment: show me your Fragment Transaction Code.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar this happens on the DrawerLayout's onClick:                      ```GameFragment gameFragment = (GameFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(GameFragment.TAG);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (gameFragment == null) {
            gameFragment = GameFragment.newInstance();
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, gameFragment, GameFragment.TAG);
        transaction.addToBackStack(GameFragment.TAG);
        transaction.commit();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The problem was that I was finding the IDs in the `getView()` method itself, instead of extending the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` in the ViewHolder class and getting IDs that way:

```
public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    // reuse views
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_word, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (i <= mWordCards.size()-1){
        viewHolder.text.setText(mWordCards.get(i).getWord());
        convertView.setOnDragListener(new ItemDragListener(mWordCards.get(i)));
    }

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    ImageView mCloseBtn;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.word_text);
        mCloseBtn = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
    }
```